Exercise 7.1.1 - Analysis I - Terence Tao
I have a problem, while proving part (b) of lemma 7.1.4.
We wish to prove the following:

(b) Let $m \leq n$ be integers, $k$ be another integer, and let $a_i$ be a real number assigned to each integer $m \leq i \leq n$. Then we have $$\sum_{i=m}^{n} a_i = \sum_{j=m+k}^{n+k} a_{j-k}$$

To prove this statement, I kept m and k fixed, and induced over n. To complete the inductive step and use the inductive hypothesis, the following equality must be used: $$ \sum_{j=m+k}^{n+k+1} a_{j-k} = \sum_{j=m+k}^{n+k} a_{j-k} + a_{(n+k+1)-k}$$
I know that this equality should be used and it makes sense, but I don't know why it is true, since the original definition given by the author for finite series mentions the following:

Definition 7.1.1 (Finite series). Let $m, n$ be integers, and let $(a_i)_{i=m}^{n}$ be a finite sequence of real numbers. Then we define the finite sum (or finite series) $\sum_{i=m}^{n} a_i$ by the recursive formula $$ \sum_{i=m}^{n} a_i := 0 \text{ whenever } n<m;$$ $$ \sum_{i=m}^{n+1} a_i := (\sum_{i=m}^{n} a_i) + a_{n+1} \text{ whenever } n \geq m -1. $$

In this definition, the summation index is kept as $i$ in both $i=m$ and $a_i$; while in the expression I must use for the inductive step, I have $j=m+k$ and $a_{j-k}$, so the index $j$ is not maintained. On this last point, I don't know how I should use the definition.
Thanks in advance.

Here's why it follows from Definition 7.1.1. Observe that, by merely manipulating the index, we have
$$
\sum_{j=m+k}^{n+k+1} a_{j-k} = \sum_{j-k=m}^{n+k+1} a_{j-k}
$$
which now follows the notation set in the definition.

What you have done is correct:
$$\sum_{i=m}^{n+1} a_i = \sum_{i=m}^{n} a_i + a_{n+1}  = \sum_{j=m+k}^{n+k} a_{j-k} + a_{(n+k+1)-k} = \sum_{j=m+k}^{n+k+1} a_{j-k} .$$
